# Insert content from data-reactid into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the price range out of this data-reactid:

```
<span data-reactid=".0.0.5.0.0.$PricePerXFacet.1.0.$Price-sort=2[10 TO 20}.$Price-sort=2[10 TO 20}.0.0.2">$0.38 to $0.77</span>
```

and insert it into a div.

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[data-reactid=.0.0.5.0.0.$PricePerXFacet.1.0.$Price-sort=2[10 TO 20}.$Price-sort=2[10 TO 20}.0.0.2]").appendTo('#Content');
});
</script>
```

Also, how can I incorporate this into the script?: `substring(0, 3);`

Comment: `appendTo('#Content')` has a typo, `<div id="content"></div>`, it should be `appendTo('#content')`

Comment: woah, that's weird

Comment: is it possible to add an id to that `span`? Selecting an element by it's full data attribute just to read the attribute itself seems a bit redundant.